# associative array, json to php

Tags: php, json

In my php file im using the following,

```
$obj = ($_POST['data']);
var_dump(json_decode($obj,true));
```

And i see this result. Is this the correct format? and how do i access the array.

eg, set a new variable $newID the same as row1 id

```
array(4) {
  ["row0"]=>
  string(92) "{"id":"157","name":"123","basic":"123123123","submitter":"Keith","status":"review"}"
  ["row1"]=>
  string(169) "{"id":"158","name":"TEST RESOURCE","basic":"Please state the type of work.","submitter":"Keith","status":"review"}"
  ["row2"]=>
  string(107) "{"id":"159","name":"TEST OTHER","basic":"testing for other","submitter":"Keith","status":"review"}"
  ["row3"]=>
  string(160) "{"id":"160","name":"Name","basic":"type of work","submitter":"Keith","status":"review"}"
}
```

heres whats in POST in firebug

```
data    {"row0":"{\"id\":\"157\",\"name\":\"123\",\"basic\":\"123123123\",\"submitter\":\"Keith\",\"status\":\"review\"}","row1":"{\"id\":\"158\",\"name\":\"TEST RESOURCE\",\"basic\":\"Please state the type of work.\",\"submitter\":\"Keith\",\"status\":\"review\"}","row2":"{\"id\":\"159\",\"name\":\"TEST OTHER\",\"basic\":\"testing for other\",\"submitter\":\"Keith\",\"status\":\"review\"}","row3":"{\"id\":\"160\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"basic\":\"type of work\",\"submitter\":\"Keith\",\"status\":\"review\"}"}
```

Comment: Can you post the original JSON-string you are getting?

Comment: updated with what post data i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each "row" of the array is another JSON string. It seems like the data was double-encoded, like:

```
$array = json_encode(
    array(
        'row0' => json_encode(array('id' => '157', ...)),
        ...
    )
)
```

This is incorrectly encoded data, unless you wanted JSON objects inside JSON objects. To work with it, you need to `json_decode` each individual item again. Better though: fix the encoding step.

Comment: Yes each json object is another jsonobject. Try something like : 

$result = array();
$var = json_decode($obj,true);
foreach ($var as $k=>$v) $result[$k]=json_decode($v,true);